# Fix issue with chrome update version 65.0.3325.146 (Official Build) (64-bit) for mac - dev-tools

Tags: google-chrome

I facing a problem with mobile inspect which a problem occur when i inspect any site i see only top-left-quarter of the site and the rest is white blank screen like this screenshot 
[image]

any help?

Comment: Same here. Did you did you find the solution?

Comment: I think next update will fix this issue .. we've to wait it.

Answer (score 0):

Like as expected .. the issue has been fixed in update Version 65.0.3325.162 (Official Build) (64-bit)